# Array member becomes the same after push in my Ruby code

Tags: ruby

In my Ruby code, a long hex string is parsed and pushed into a data array (`avl_data_array.push(avl_data)`). After pushing, when I use `puts` to display the array, all the elements are the same...

The code is:

```
data_hex_string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

avl_data_header = {}
avl_data = {}
avl_data_array = [] 
avl_data_footer = {}

avl_data_header[:packet_len] = data_hex_string[0..3]
avl_data_header[:packet_id] = data_hex_string[4..7]
avl_data_header[:not_usable_byte] = data_hex_string[8..9]
avl_data_header[:avl_packet_id] = data_hex_string[10..11]
avl_data_header[:imei_len] = data_hex_string[12..15]

imei_len_dec = data_hex_string[12..15].to_i(16)
current_add = 16
offset = imei_len_dec * 2
avl_data_header[:imei] = data_hex_string[current_add..(current_add+offset-1)]

current_add = current_add+offset
offset = 2
avl_data_header[:codec_id] = data_hex_string[current_add..(current_add+offset-1)]

current_add = current_add+offset
offset = 2
avl_data_header[:number_data1] = data_hex_string[current_add..(current_add+offset-1)]

data_num = avl_data_header[:number_data1].to_i(16)

for a in 0..(data_num-1) do
  current_add = current_add+offset
  offset = 2 * 8
  avl_data[:timestamp] = data_hex_string[current_add..(current_add+offset-1)]

  current_add = current_add+offset
  offset = 2
  avl_data[:priority] = data_hex_string[current_add..(current_add+offset-1)]

  current_add = current_add+offset
  offset = 2 * 4
  avl_data[:longitude] = data_hex_string[current_add..(current_add+offset-1)]

  current_add = current_add+offset
  offset = 2 * 4
  avl_data[:latitude] = data_hex_string[current_add..(current_add+offset-1)]

  current_add = current_add+offset
  offset = 2 * 2
  avl_data[:altitude] = data_hex_string[current_add..(current_add+offset-1)]

  current_add = current_add+offset
  offset = 2 * 2
  avl_data[:angle] = data_hex_string[current_add..(current_add+offset-1)]

  current_add = current_add+offset
  offset = 2
  avl_data[:satellites] = data_hex_string[current_add..(current_add+offset-1)]

  current_add = current_add+offset
  offset = 2 * 2
  avl_data[:speed] = data_hex_string[current_add..(current_add+offset-1)]
  
  avl_data_array.push(avl_data)
end

current_add = current_add+offset
offset = 2
avl_data_footer[:number_data2] = data_hex_string[current_add..(current_add+offset-1)]

current_add = current_add+offset
offset = 2 * 4
avl_data_footer[:crc_16] = data_hex_string[current_add..(current_add+offset-1)]
    
puts "header: #{avl_data_header}"
puts "data:"
puts avl_data_array
puts "footer: #{avl_data_footer}"
```

The result is:

```
header: {:packet_len=>"03D8", :packet_id=>"CAFE", :not_usable_byte=>"01", :avl_packet_id=>"D0", :imei_len=>"000F", :imei=>"383630323634303535353134323532", :codec_id=>"08", :number_data1=>"11"}
data:
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
{:timestamp=>"ED18000000000000", :priority=>"01", :longitude=>"80B97AB1", :latitude=>"1B005B29", :altitude=>"ED2A", :angle=>"EF93", :satellites=>"5C", :speed=>"0D00"}
footer: {:number_data2=>"00", :crc_16=>"00000000"}
```

The element in array `data` should be different. I am Ruby newbie, but it seems the grammer in my code is correct. Why this happens?

Comment: Do you really need that much code to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why this happens?

You never change `avl_data`. It is always the same object. Hence, you push the same object to the `Array` in `avl_data_array` over and over again.

Here is a reduced version of your code demonstrating the problem more clearly:

```ruby
single_array_element = {}
array = []

3.times do |i|
  single_array_element[:i] = i
  array << single_array_element
end

array.all? {|el| single_array_element.object_id == el.object_id}
#=> true

array
#=> [{ i: 2 }, { i: 2 }, { i: 2 }]
```

> I am Ruby newbie, but it seems the grammer in my code is correct.

The syntax is indeed correct, otherwise the program would not even run – the parser would abort with a `SyntaxError`. But the *semantics* aren't: The code you wrote is 100% valid Ruby code, it is not an error.

Ruby is doing exactly what you are telling her to do, you just told it to do the wrong thing.

Comment: Thanks. @Jorg, I do not understand why I never change avl_data. It looks like avl_data is changed every time in the loop. If add  "puts single_array_element" in the look of your reduced version, it display {:i=>0}{:i=>1}{:i=>2}

Comment: You *mutate the `Hash` that is referenced by `avl_data`*. But you *never change `avl_data`*. You assign a `Hash` to it on line 4, *and then never assign to it again*, which means during the entire runtime of your program, there is only that single `Hash` which you keep appending to `avl_data_array` over and over again.

Comment: @leilei "changing avl_data" can mean two very different things: 1) mutating the hash, `avl_data` is referring to (changing the existing values). 2) assigning a new hash to the `avl_data` variable (which is what Jörg means when saying _"you never change `avl_data`"_). If you add the same hash object multiple times (what you did), then changing its values will affect all elements (because they are the same object). In order to get different objects, you have to create a new hash instance each time, e.g. by moving `avl_data = {}` into the loop.